# locking down skype

Tags: security, skype

I am interested in using Skype for IM,voice,etc in our offices but this adds some insecurity.
How can i block one user from adding more contacts than those alowed, this way he coudn't send files or chat with non-business contacts ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised if this was not possible using the [Skype Manager](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-gb/business/skype-manager).

Comment: I believe you can do so with member list controls in Skype for Business with Skype Manager.
http://download.skype.com/share/business/guides/skype-manager-user-guide.pdf

Comment: going to try this right now!

Comment: nope. it's not in their features.  or at least i could not find it ... any other sugestion ?

Comment: Have you looked at page 12 of the PDF that h4rrydog linked to?  Does that not cover it?  Maybe you could try asking in the Skype Business Forum.  http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showforum=32&s=949f4e0e67bb6876a1a2eaa60bb252d0

Comment: no. it does not cover this problem